# Can I build a bar graphs from this clustering data

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-science

I am trying to make a bar graph or a stacked bar graph with the count  of each city.

[image: The data set]

The x-axis should be the the label of cluster and y-axis should be the count.

Something like these

[image: Chart example]

[image]

Where the colors are different cities.

I have tried to use the hist funtions from pandas but cannot separate the cities.
[image]

Comment: This is not a histogram, but a bar chart.

Comment: Please do not provide data as images. I suggest reading [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and editing your question. If that is a pandas dataframe. We don't know.

Comment: With seaborn? `sns.countplot(x=df['cluster'])`?

Answer (score 2):

I tend to lean towards plotly, in Jupyter, because it's interactive.

https://plotly.com/python/histograms/

https://www.fredlich.com/works/how-to-make-a-countplot-in-seaborn-plotly-and-matplotlib

https://towardsdatascience.com/histograms-with-plotly-express-complete-guide-d483656c5ad7

Also, Seaborn has some nice features too!

https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html